# Cross platform method of getting abbreviated weekday name

Tags: c, cross-platform

```
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){

char *firstDayAb;
firstDayAb = nl_langinfo(ABDAY_1);
printf("\nFirst day ab is %s\n", firstDayAb);

return 0;
}
```

This code works fine on Mac and Linux but it doesn't work on windows due to absence of langinfo.h. How to avoid using langinfo.h? Or maybe there is another way of getting abbreviated weekday name?

Comment: If you are using `cygwin` you can get the missing .h by reinstalling cygwin. You'll be able to select more packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  struct tm timeinfo = {0};
  char buffer [80];
  timeinfo.tm_wday = 1;
  strftime (buffer, 80, "First day ab is %a", &timeinfo);
  puts (buffer);      
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a link [Code for header file is given here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid9E9EC2584CF169CC6F2203C0C088282937E4B449.aspx?s=file%3awindows.h). It uses KDE32 on windows. I hope this helps you.